# multiple seasonality Time series analysis in Python

Tags: python, time-series, data-science, dummy-variable, arima

I have a daily time series dataset that I am using Python SARIMAX method to predict for future. But I do not know how to write codes in python that accounts for multiple seasonalities. As far as I know, SARIMAX takes care of only one seasonality but I want to check for weekly, monthly, and quarterly seasonalities. I know to capture day of the week seasonality, I should create 6 dummy variables, To capture day of the month seasonality, create 30 dummy variables, and To capture month of the year, create 11 dummy variables. But I don't know how to incorporate it with the main SARIMAX function in Python? I mean SARIMAX is just a function that does the autoregressive, moving average and the differencing parts but how should I include multiple seasonality codes in my time series analysis with SARIMAX? So far, I know how to create dummy variables for each category but don't know how to replicate it to the entire dataset? After that I don't know how to write Python codes that do SARIMAX and captures multiple seasonalities at the same time.

I am in need of help for Python code that can do it.

Please advise accordingly

Regards

Comment: For a more robust and flexible approach: https://towardsdatascience.com/is-gradient-boosting-good-as-prophet-for-time-series-forecasting-3dcbfd03775e

Answer (score 5):

Yes, SARIMA model is designed for dealing with a single seasonality.

- To make it work for multiple seasonality, it is possible to apply a
  method called Fourier terms.
- Secondly, there is a better method for time series data with multiple
  seasonality effects which is called TBABS. Here is an example that
  includes codes and explanation for both approaches:
  https://medium.com/intive-developers/forecasting-time-series-with-multiple-seasonalities-using-tbats-in-python-398a00ac0e8a
- Thirdly, you can check https://facebook.github.io/prophet/ which also
  brings up an easier way to this issue.
- For a deeper research, you can always google terms "time series" with "multiple seasonality" or "multiple seasonal effect"

Comment: By "Fourier terms" are you refer to a partial expansion of a [Fourier series](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierSeries.html)?

Answer (score 2):

One option for handling multiple seasonalities in python is the Multiple Seasonal-Trend decomposition using LOESS (MSTL) functionality from the [statsmodels](https://www.statsmodels.org/) package.  Both [MSTL function documentation](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.seasonal.MSTL.html) and an [MSTL decomposition notebook](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/examples/notebooks/generated/mstl_decomposition.html) are provided.

Some example code showing decomposition of daily and weekly seasonalities:

```
from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import MSTL


res = MSTL(data, periods=(24, 24 * 7)).fit()
res.plot()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

The `res` object can now be used for forecasting.  I believe the `MSTL` implementations are currently limited to additive seasonalities.  There is no support for exogenous regressors.

The statsmodels `MSTL` function is based on the [work by Rob Hyndman and co.](https://robjhyndman.com/publications/mstl/) available in the R [forecast](https://pkg.robjhyndman.com/forecast/reference/mstl.html) package.  It uses the [LOESS (locally estimated scatterplot smoothing)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_regression) method.